# Is the Baireness a 3-space property of topological groups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, locally-convex-spaces

It is [known](https://staff.science.uva.nl/j.vanmill/papers/papers1986/MillPol_3-1986.pdf) that the product of two Baire spaces can be meager.

On the other hand, by a recent result of [Li and Zsilinszky](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.06197) the product of two Baire spaces is Baire if one of the spaces is countably cellular (i.e., does not contains an uncountable family of pairwIse disjoint open sets).

This suggests the following

> **Problem.** Let $H$ be a closed normal subgroup of a topological group $G$, and $G/H$ be the quotient topological group. Assume that the spaces $H$ and $G/H$ are Baire and one of them is countably cellular. Is the space $G$ Baire?

It seems that this question is open even for locally convex linear topological spaces.

---

**Added in Edit.** I was informed by [Gabriel Andre Asmat Medina](https://mathoverflow.net/users/138770/gabriel-medina) that the mentioned result of Li and Zsilinszky has some problems in the proof as it contradicts the CH-example of [White](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-048-01/S0002-9939-1975-0362249-1/S0002-9939-1975-0362249-1.pdf) who constructed a countably cellular Baire Tychonoff space $X$ whose square $X\times X$ is meager. The example of White has the structure of quasitopological group, but it is not a topological group.